# Is there a merge/comparison tool like VisualStudio but for the Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, visual-studio

I would like to find a tool like VisualStudio but for the Mac. Specifically what I need is to be able to go "back in time" in Git repos to perform side by side file comparisons of code. I know with VS you can do this, is there anything out there for the Mac that will do the same thing? I'm writing in Ruby on Rails if that makes a difference.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+compare+files) might have some helpful leads for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code for mac works okay for this if you use the GitLens extension. You can also use a more bloated IDE like RubyMine. You are probably going to be limited on native stuff so find an extension you like in an editor that you like.